# Magento: Shipping price based on weight

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I want to apply the following shipping rules in the magento:

```
1-5kg - £5.95
6-10kg - £7.95
11-100kg + £0.21p per kilo on top of the £7.95 price.
```

I am facing problem with applying 0.21p per kilo in the last rule. Please advise if this is possible in magento or if any 3rd party extension can do this?

Comment: Currently where you configuring these things?

Comment: I am not configuring these anywhere at the moment, but for the first two we can configure using shipping table rates. But not sure about the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this using the built in table rates method.  Go to system > configuration in admin, then on the left, choose shipping methods and find table rates.  Switch the view scope in the top left to your website view (not the store view) to reveal the import/export options.  Make sure the condition is set to 'weight vs destination'.

Create a csv like this;

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
*   *   *   1   5.95
*   *   *   5.01    7.95
*   *   *   11  8.16
*   *   *   12  8.37
*   *   *   13  8.58
*   *   *   14  8.79
*   *   *   15  9
*   *   *   16  9.21 
*   *   *   17  9.42
*   *   *   18  9.63
*   *   *   19  9.84
*   *   *   20  10.05
*   *   *   21  10.26
*   *   *   22  10.47
*   *   *   23  10.68
*   *   *   24  10.89
*   *   *   25  11.1
*   *   *   26  11.31
```

etc, upload it, save and jobs a good'n :)